# Input string is not in correct format error for C# program

Tags: c#, exception

I want to print Ready if CL (count lucky) is greater than CUL(count unlucky). My criteria is N is some number and array A is upto N. and the contents of array are checked whether individual content is even/odd. If even CL++, or else CUL++

When I tried to enter input in the format

 5 

1 2 3 4 5

the error is "input string is not in correct format".

I can get the output if the format of the input is

 5 

1

2

3

4

5

What should be changed to get the output while using earlier format?

Code:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (N <= 100)
        {
            int[] A = new int[N];
            int cL = 0; int CUL = 0;
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                A[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (A[j] % 2 != 0)
                {

                    CUL++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cL++;
                }

            }
            if (cL > CUL)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("READY FOR BATTLE");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NOT READY");
            }


        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Just think about this: how should `ToInt32` make `1 2 3 4 5` into *one* integer? Also think about this: if you `ReadLine` and get `1 2 3 4 5`, and only use one value, you've lost the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When input is in form of `"1 2 3 4 5"` (a *string*) you have to *split* it into items and *parse* each item into integer:

```
  int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  String line = Console.ReadLine();

  int[] A = line
    .Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
    .ToArray();

  // given N differs from actual one
  if (N != A.Length) {
    // Throw an exception or re-assign N
    N = A.Length;
  }

 // A as well as N are obtained

 for (j = 0; j < N; j++) 
   if A[j] % 2 != 0
     CUL++;
   else  
     cL++;

 if (cL > CUL)
   Console.WriteLine("READY FOR BATTLE");
 else
   Console.WriteLine("NOT READY");
```